# How to Clone Row With Value

Tags: javascript

I want to clone row with same value according last row that i have filled. Here is screenshot my app.

1. https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9_Xi3waidNLUE0zaHlONHNWcjQ
2. My expected result https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9_Xi3waidNLYnVnVFlhSUx4WWM

Here is My Code :

```
function addTableRowHasilProduksi() {
row = parseInt($('#tableRowHasilProduksi').val()) + 1;
$('#plusButtonHasilProduksi').remove();
var html = ' \
<tr id="rowTableHasilProduksi_' + row + '"> \
  <td> \
   <select id="typepartid_' + row + '" class="form-control" onchange="myFunction(' + row + ')" name="typepartid_' + row + '"> \
   ' + htmlPartId + ' \
  </td> \
 <td>\
    <select id="hasilproduksi_' + row + '" class="form-control" placeholder="select" onchange="hasilProduksiChage(' + row + ')" name="hasilproduksi_' + row + '"> \
      <option value="-">--Select--</option>\
      <option value="Good">Good</option>\
      <option value="Repair">Repair</option>\
      <option value="Reject">Reject</option>\
    </select> \
  </td> \
  <td><input id="qty_' + row + '" type="text" class="form-control"  onkeydown="return numbersonly(this, event);" onkeyup="javascript:tandaPemisahTitik(this);" name="qty_' + row + '" /> \
  </td> \
   <td><input id="waktu_' + row + '" type="text" class="form-control" name="waktu_' + row + '" onfocusout="waktuOnFocusOut(this)" onfocusin="waktuOnFocusIn(this)"/></td> \
  <td id="tdTypeReject_' + row + '"> \
    <select id="typereject_' + row + '" class="form-control" name="typereject_' + row + '"> \
    ' + htmlTypeReject + ' \
    </select> \
  </td> \
  <td><input id="keteranganreject_' + row + '" type="text" class="form-control" name="keteranganreject_' + row + '"/></td> \
  <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" onclick="deleteRowHasilProduksi(' + row + ')">x</button></td> \
</tr> \
<tr id="plusButtonHasilProduksi"> \
  <td colspan="7"><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" style="width:100%" onclick="addTableRowHasilProduksi()">+</button></td> \
</tr>';
$('#tableHasilProduksi > tbody').append(html);
//variable row table add +1
$('#tableRowHasilProduksi').val(row);
$('#plusButtonHasilProduksi').attr('onclick', 'addTableRowDowntime()');}
```

Any Help can be appreciated.

Comment: Both of the URLs are not publicly available

Comment: @TyBourque Thanks, i have updated my question, lets check again. and please help me

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I have extracted a couple things out to make this a little simpler. First Assuming your first row is always visible you don't need to store the template in js. Just use the dom to get the template.

All you need to do is get the row your looking to copy.

```
var lastTableRow =  $("#tableRowHasilProduksiBody tr:nth-last-child(2)" )
```

Get The value of that selection.

```
var selectedValue = $( lastTableRow ).find('.typepartid').val();
```

Clone the Row.

```
var newRow = lastTableRow.clone();
```

Get a count of the Rows

```
var rowCount = $('.rowTableHasilProduksi').length;
```

Do your attribute manipulation and add it back into the dom.

```
  $( newRow ).find('.typepartid').val(selectedValue);
  // Set to blank and Add Ids,.. Etc here
  $( newRow ).find('.hasilproduksi').val('-').attr('name','DataName' + rowCount );
```

Simple as that. Here is a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/vatujocico/edit?html,js,output) Hope this helps.

Comment: pardon me, my code doesn't work, beceuse my code is different. i use combobox with function to call typepartid. Check my code https://jsfiddle.net/mekmea09/1/

Comment: If you need to run code when your combo box changes just use the jquery onChange event listener to bind to that function

Comment: can you please write the code according my code like this https://jsfiddle.net/mekmea09/1/ . because i still dont understand